# ¿Como hago para tener mejor control de los estilos de un slider con Swiper.js?

Tags: reactjs, swiper, styled-components

Pasa que estoy trabajando los carruseles con una librería llamada "Swiper.js" Sin embargo a veces ha sido un lio querer mover un estilo o algo sin que no haga efecto, viendo eso no sé si hay un módulo de la librería que me permita mayor flexibilidad porque la verdad es tedioso maniobrarlo [Anexo codigo]

```
    import React from "react";
    import styled from "styled-components";

    // Import Swiper React components
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
    import {
      Pagination,
      EffectCoverflow,
      Navigation,
     Keyboard,
    } from "swiper/modules";

    // Import Swiper styles
    import "swiper/css/bundle";

    // Import assets esentials for slider
    import SampleImage from "/public/assets/images/projects-resources/slider-images/desktop- 
    1920x1080.jpg";
    import SampleImage2 from "/public/assets/images/projects-resources/slider-images/fanart-fallout.jpg";

const SliderMainContainer = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;

  .swiper {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .swiper-slide {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-position: center;

    &:not(.swiper-slide-active) {
      filter: blur(0.8em);
      opacity: 0.5;
      transition: opacity 400ms;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 3em;
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
`;

    const Projects = () => {
      return (
    

    <SliderMainContainer id="proyectos">
          <Swiper
            effect={"coverflow"}
            speed={900}
            centeredSlides={true}
            slidesPerView={2}
            initialSlide={1}
            grabCursor={true}
            keyboard={true}
            coverflowEffect={{
              rotate: 15,
              stretch: 50,
              depth: 100,
              modifier: 1,
            }}
            loop={true}
            modules={[EffectCoverflow, Pagination, Navigation, Keyboard]}
            className="mySwiper"
          >
            <SwiperSlide>
              <img src={SampleImage} />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <img src={SampleImage2} />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <img src={SampleImage} />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <img src={SampleImage2} />
            </SwiperSlide>
          </Swiper>
        </SliderMainContainer>
      );
    };
```

Como ven en el ejemplo, he querido tener mayor flexibilidad en el diseño, pero a veces las transiciones, bordes, animaciones e incluso dimensiones no surten efecto. Mi pregunta es, ¿hay un modulo o una manera de tener una mejor efectividad en cuanto a diseño de estos sliders que ofrece la libreria?

Comment: En la Doc no viene ningún ejemplo donde indique que se puede inyectar un styled component personalizado mas allá de Swiper styles, imagino que si descartas `SliderMainContainer`, la librería funcionará bien, parece que tendrás que lidiar con eso o cambiar de librería, y ¿Esto donde esta? `className="mySwiper"`; por otro lado, en la última version de Swiper están recomendando migrar de Swiper React components a Swiper Element